# ¿Por qué obtengo EnvironmentNotWritableError al instalar nbextensions configurator?

Tags: jupyter, anaconda3

Intento instalar **jupyter nbextensions configurator** con **anaconda3** y obtengo el siguiente error:

```
enri@enri-260-p100ns:/media/enri/Mi_Proyecto$ conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_nbextensions_configurator
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /home/enri/anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - jupyter_nbextensions_configurator


The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  jupyter_contrib_c~ conda-forge/noarch::jupyter_contrib_core-0.3.3-py_2
  jupyter_nbextensi~ conda-forge/linux-64::jupyter_nbextensions_configurator-0.4.1-py38h578d9bd_2
  python_abi         conda-forge/linux-64::python_abi-3.8-1_cp38

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  conda               pkgs/main::conda-4.9.2-py38h06a4308_0 --> conda-forge::conda-4.9.2-py38h578d9bd_0


Proceed ([y]/n)? y

Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: failed

EnvironmentNotWritableError: The current user does not have write permissions to the target environment.
  environment location: /home/enri/anaconda3
  uid: 1000
  gid: 1000
```

¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema?. ¿Cómo hago para dar ese permiso?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he resuelto haciendo  `sudo chown -R enri:enri /home/enri/anaconda3`